# How can I add column to a list that I have imported

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, issue-tracking

I have created an issue tracking list , then I have imported it in a Wiki page,

The problem is that I don't see the same columns as when I open the list in it's own page.

[image: Here's a screen print]

I would like to add existing columns to this list.

Comment: Change list view

Comment: Changing list view redirect me to another page but I will always have the same list columns when I go to the page where I have imported the list

Comment: You can modify the view instead and show columns whichever you want in this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below steps:**

1. Edit your wiki page.
2. Edit your list view webpart.
3. Click on "Edit the current view". (See screenshot below)
4. Select columns you want to show and save the view. Now you will see the column you selected on your page.

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped. You r welcome :-)